# Use jquery to target element parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, parent

I have the follow list that I  need to be able to hide all accept for what is actually in focus with class active.

```
 <Ul>
        <Li>something</li>
          <ul>
           <li>Something</>
           <li>Something</>
          </ul>
        <Li>something</li>
        <Li>something</li>
        <Li>
            <Ul>
                <Li class="active">something</li>
                <Li>omething</li>
            </Ul>
        </li>
        <Li>something</li>
    </Ul>
```

I need to be able to use .hide() on all li that are not related to the bottom level one with the active class

The result would be

```
<Ul>
  <Li>something</li>
  <Li>something</li>
  <Li>something</li>
    <Li>
        <Ul>
            <Li class="active">something</li>
            <Li>omething</li>
        </Ul>
    </li>
  <Li>something</li>
 </Ul>
```

Comment: [What have you Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Almost every combination of $('.active').parent('Li').hide() I could think of but it always removes the direct parent and all the siblings. I just need all the siblings to the top level li to be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [traverse up the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) yo find the first level `li` element and its siblings. If you have only two levels, this should work:

```
$('li.active').parent().closest('li').siblings().children('ul').hide();
```

If you have more than two levels, I suggest to give the root `ul` a class or ID:

```
$('li.active').closest('#root > li').siblings().children('ul').hide();
```

Comment: It is kind of working for me. In my actual application I need to hide child items to the li that are not related. See my edits above.

Comment: @Rob: Then select those by changing my solution to `...siblings().children('ul').hide();` (I updated it). Have a look at all the traversal methods that are available and read their documentation. It will save you a lot of time eventually.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Going up, down, and sideways in the dom makes my head spin.

Answer (score 0):

`$( 'li:not(.active,.active ~ li,.active li,:has(.active))' ).hide();`

This selects all `li` elements, but excludes (by using `:not()`):

1. `.active` — the active `li` element itself
2. `.active ~ li` — sibling `li` elements of the active `li` element
3. `.active li` — descendant `li` elements of the active `li` element
4. `has(.active)` — `li` elements that have the active `li` element as its descendant

[*jsfiddle demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/wskyq/)

If you want to keep showing descendants of the active `li` element's siblings as well, add `.active ~ li li` to the `:not()` selectors:

`$( 'li:not(.active,.active ~ li,.active li,.active ~ li li,:has(.active))' ).hide();`

[*jsfiddle demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/wskyq/1/)

Following up on OP's first comment to this answer:

Just add an `li` before the initial selector:

`$( 'li li:not(.active,.active ~ li,.active li,.active ~ li li,:has(.active))' ).hide();`

[*jsfiddle demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/wskyq/2/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to preserve the top li and get rid of any children of other li's not related to my active element. See my example above.

Comment: @Rob Concerning your first comment: that wasn't part of the initial requirements. However, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Rob And just leave out those selectors in the `:not()` condition, that you don't want to use.